# Ant build failure due to non-loading dependent Task class

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

```
Buildfile: /.../build.xml
build:
buildtests:
tests:

BUILD FAILED
/.../build.xml:43: Problem: failed to create task or type junit
Cause: Could not load a dependent class org/apache/tools/ant/Task
   It is not enough to have Ant's optional JARs
   you need the JAR files that the optional tasks depend upon.
   Ant's optional task dependencies are listed in the manual.
Action: Determine what extra JAR files are needed, and place them in one of:
    -/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib
    -/Users/cjwalsh/.ant/lib
    -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem


Total time: 512 milliseconds
```

... and I've checked all the recommended directories, and yet I still keep getting this build failure. The specific JAR 'ant.jar', which I've looked into, has the class 'Task', and it is in the '/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib' directory. Do I need to manually add this classpath to my build.xml as well? Here is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="springapp" basedir="." default="build">
<property file="build.properties"></property>

<property name="src.dir" value="src"></property>
<property name="web.dir" value="war"></property>
<property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"></property>
<property name="name" value="springapp"></property>
<property name="test.dir" value="test"></property>

<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="servlet*.jar"></include>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"></pathelement>
</path>

<target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true" deprecation="false" optimize="false"
        failonerror="true">

        <src path="${src.dir}" />
        <classpath refid="master-classpath" />  
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="buildtests" description="Compile test tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
        deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">

        <src path="${test.dir}"></src>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"></classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="tests" depends="build, buildtests" description="Run tests">
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="false" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="tests.failed"
        showoutput="true">

        <classpath refid="master-classpath"></classpath>

        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />

        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Tests.*" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>

    <fail if="tests.failed">
        tests.failed=${tests.failed}
        ***********************************************************************
        ***********************************************************************
        ****    One or more tests failed! Check the output ...  *************** 
        ***********************************************************************
        ***********************************************************************
    </fail>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy the application">
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as WAR file">
    <war destfile="${name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"></include>
        </fileset>
    </war>
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*.war"></include>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"></include>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"></classpath>
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"></classpath>
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath" />
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"></classpath>
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"></classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}" username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}"
        war="${name}" />
</target>

<target name="reload" description="Reload applicatio in Tomcat">
    <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}" username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}" />
</target>

<target name="start" description="Start tomcat application">
    <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}" username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
        path="/${name}" />
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
    <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}" />
</target>

<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}" />
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting ant from within Eclipse?

Please check in the menu {Run | External Tools Configuration...} that the Classpath tab contains "Ant Home". After expanding, does it point to valid files?

Comment: Yes, I am running Ant from Eclipse. Under the External Tools Configuration > Classpath tab, it lists under User Entries, Ant Home (Default) and Additional Tasks & Support. The list of JAR's under Ant Home contain all the necessary Ant JAR's that are within the '/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib':

Comment: Here's the list of jars under Ant Home: ant.jar, ant-antlr.jar, ant-apache-bcel.jar, ant-apache-bsf.jar, ant-apache-log4j.jar, ant-apache-oro.jar, ant-apache-regexp.jar, ant-apache-resolver.jar, ant-commons-logging.jar, ant-commons-net.jar, ant-jai.jar, ant-javamail.jar, ant-jdepend.jar, ant-jmf.jar, ant-jsch.jar, ant-junit.jar, ant-launcher.jar, ant-netrexx.jar, ant-nodeps.jar, ant-starteam.jar, ant-stylebook.jar, ant-swing.jar, ant-trax.jar, ant-weblogin.jar

Comment: thank you! this solved the problem I was having with tomcat ant tasks. I had to add catalina-ant.jar to the list of JARs.